Spotfire.Dxp.PackageBuilder-Console.exe throwing Error code 0x8009002D
Hi guys I am getting following error while trying to build package via Spotfire.Dxp.PackageBuilder-Console.exe, anybody facing same or have solution. thank you in advance
enter image description here
-Wasiq
I am trying to sing package while building it and getting error. causing spotfire plugin to give unknow publisher warning.
